# Multiple Matches on manifest.json

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I was wanting to match my chrome extension run on both `google.com` and `twitch.tv.` I tried these two ways:

**first way:**

```
 "content_scripts": [ {
        "exclude_globs":    [  ],
        "include_globs":    [ "*" ],
        "js":["jquery.user.js","h.js", "main.js"],
        "matches": ["*//google.com", "*//twitch.tv/"],
        "run_at": "document_end",
        "permissions":["tabs","<all_urls>"]

    } ],
```

**second way:**

```
"content_scripts": [ {
    "exclude_globs":    [  ],
    "include_globs":    [ "*" ],
    "js":["jquery.user.js","h.js", "main.js"],
    "matches": ["*//google.com, *//twitch.tv/"],
    "run_at": "document_end",
    "permissions":["tabs","<all_urls>"]

} ],
```

The way where I separated the two with a quotation mark crashed and didn't work, the one where I didn't separate the `URL's` ran only the first `URL` (google)

So is there a way to make it run on two `URLs`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`permissions` goes outside `content_scripts`. The match pattern for `twitch.tv` has an extra slash. Try `*//*.twitch.tv`

**manifest.json**

```
"content_scripts": [ {
        "js":["jquery.user.js","h.js", "main.js"],
        "matches": ["*//*.google.com", "*//*.twitch.tv"],
        "run_at": "document_end",
    } ],
"permissions":["tabs","<all_urls>"]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. if you need to load conman js and css for both domain.

   "content_scripts": [
   {
     "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*","https://www.twitch.tv/*"],
     "css": ,
     "js": 
     "run_at": "document_end" //add this tag if you want to load js and css after document is ready
   }
   ],
2. if you need to load  indivisual css and js for each domain

   "content_scripts": [
       {
         "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"],
         "css": ,
         "js": 
         "run_at": "document_end" //add this tag if you want to load js and css after document is ready
       },
       {
         "matches": ["https://www.twitch.tv/*"],
         "css": ,
         "js": 
         "run_at": "document_end" //add this tag if you want to load js and css after document is ready
       }
     ]

Comment: if you read through my question i already tried your first way and it didn't work

Comment: FYI:- if you are made changes in manifest.JSon you must reload for take changes efface. https://mixandgo.com/assets/blog/chrome_extension_reload-5489be1d112b16f2b65afe06b91b0d3b3d958a52ecbc81de990eca444542f7d7.png